# Want to write T-SQL Code to insert single row from text file into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to write one Transact SQL code which can read a text file and insert data into SQL Server 2008 database table. How can I do that? Text file is separated by comma and has only 1 record. But I don't want to use bulk insert or any other auto method. I want to do it by coding for doing some processing.

- Text file path: `C:\fakepath\record.txt`
- Text file content (only 1 row) - `1,John,2000`
- Table name: `Employee`
- Structure - `Id,Name,Salary`

Can you help me out to write down script?

Thanks !

Comment: TSQL script will not read a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this method in the past on 05. While you said you didn't want to use bulk it's effective: [Reading a text file with SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007857/reading-a-text-file-with-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

`BULK INSERT` should be easiest way to do this.

Otherwise, you can try `OPENROWSET`

```
   select 
      c1 
   from 
      OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\fakepath\record.txt',SINGLE_CLOB) as T1(c1)
```