# r: "$(fileName)" in a script called from sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, file-io, cmd, sqlcmd

I'm trying to create a script just to run other scripts and do some extra stuff in case of successful or failure.

You have the full code on [this link](https://gist.github.com/nescalante/0ccbe86146393c2c1ee1) just to try to be clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I want to:

```
-- DO SOME STUFF HERE

r: "$(fileName)"

-- MORE STUFF HERE
```

and call it from `sqlcmd` this way:

```
sqlcmd -i "RunScript.sql" -v fileName="someFileName.sql" -s server -d database
```

But I can't, I'm getting the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 19 Incorrect syntax
>   near 'someFileName.sql'.

So, it seems that the little [`r:`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickgallucci/archive/2007/09/03/sqlcmd-and-the-power-of-the-little-r.aspx) couldn't be used with a parameter on his side.

Just to clarify, `someFileName.sql` isn't in the SQL Server, but in my machine, so I couldn't use [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008047/1353771) to read the file. In fact, I just [tried it later](https://gist.github.com/nescalante/c9c77c96a716f4450c0d).

Is there a workaround to archive this? Any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break your current `RunScript.sql` script into separate header and footer SQL scripts and concatenate them together with a SQL script in the middle that is denoted by an input parameter to a CMD script.  For example:

`RunSQL.CMD` consists of:

```
@ECHO OFF

COPY /V /Y RunScriptHeader.sql + %1 + RunScriptFooter.sql RunScriptTemp.sql

SQLCMD -i "RunScriptTemp.sql" -s server -d database
```

- The /V does a verify on the copy
- The /Y suppresses prompting to confirm overwriting an existing file

You would run it as follows:

```
RunSQL.CMD someFileName.sql
```