# SQL select from a file

Tags: sql-server, file, select

Is it possible to execute a select from a file? I have tried the following but without any luck.

Query:

```
SELECT E_MailL 
FROM OCPR 
WHERE (CardCode) IN ('c:\temp\test.txt')
```

The file contains the customer code per line eg

```
CustomerCode1
CustomerCode2
CustomerCode3
```

Any advice or samples are welcome.

Database is SQL Server 2017.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: 'c:\temp\test.txt' in the context is a string literal. The query will return rows where CardCode is equal to that literal.

Comment: This may help...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007857/reading-a-text-file-with-sql-server

Comment: `OPENROWSET` is what you want; then you can `JOIN` to the data returned from it.

Comment: @Larnu thanks that worked with some modifilcation i added a fromatting file to catch the whitespaces. Thanks for the help